# std::vector operator [] vs. at() access

Tags: c++, vector, operator-keyword, stdvector

### <std::Vector>  Operator [] vs. at()

=========================================

I've read [somewhere](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/) that only difference between 's index access operator [] and member function at() is that at() also checks if index is valid. But, deducting from following code, it seems there is a difference

```cpp
std::vector<std::string>* namesList = readNamesFile("namesList.txt");
std::vector<Rabbit> rabbits;

const int numNAMES = namesList->size();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    rnd = rand() % numNAMES;
    rabbits.push_back(Rabbit(namesList[i]));
}
```

Code above throws

```
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'Rabbit'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Also, if I hover over (look below)

```
rabbits.push_back(Rabbit(namesList[i]));
```

^^^^^^^    I read intelliSense:

```
Error: no instance of constructor "Rabbit::Rabbit" matches the argument list
 argument types are:  (std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>)
```

However, if I access vector with at(), like this: (and only this one line is modified)

```
rabbits.push_back(Rabbit(namesList->at(i)))
```

Code works without compile and runtime errors. Can someone elaborate?

P.S: Just in case I'm providing code for .h and .cpp: http://pastebin.com/9MgNRd7m

Comment: `namesList` is a pointer. What happens when you apply `[]` to a pointer?

Comment: try `(*namesList)[i]` is it clear why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`namesList` is a pointer; so `namesList[i]` treats it as a pointer to array of vectors, giving a vector from that array. Luckily, this gives a compile-time error due to the type mismatch, rather than undefined runtime behaviour from an out-of-bounds array access.

To subscript the vector that it points to, you need to dereference the pointer first:

```
(*namesList)[i]
```

or, equivalently but perhaps less readably,

```
namesList->operator[](i)
```

You should contemplate why `readNamesFile` returns a pointer in the first place. It would make more sense to return a vector by value.

Comment: I know that namesList is a pointer, but I always thought accessing pointers with operator[] behaves in same way as accessing  normal (non-pointer) arrays. In sense int* numbers = new int[10](); I can access numbers[5], I don't need to de-reference it first. I need to understand this part.

Comment: @user1344799 Yes, it does. So it access the pointer exactly the same as it would access a non-pointer array *of vectors.* But you want `operator[]` on the `std::vector`, not on an imaginary array of vectors.

Comment: @user1344799: Indeed; just as dereferencing `int*` with `*` or `[]` gives an `int`, so dereferencing `vector*` gives a `vector`. But you don't want to dereference once to get a vector; you want to dereference twice to get a string from within the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `namesList[i]` is not `namesList->operator[](i)`.

`namesList[i]` is more like `*(namesList+i)`.

You would have to dereference your pointer to use the function directly:

```
rabbits.push_back(Rabbit((*namesList)[i]));
```